# Why is postgis not applying an index when there is a "WHERE IN" in the query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

We have a table `shops`, with column named `location` of type `GEOMETRY(POINT,4326)` and `version` of type `tinyint`
and a table
`version` with a single row containing an integer.

Why is below query not using the index for GIST(location)?

```
SELECT * FROM shops 
WHERE ("version" IN (SELECT "version" FROM "version")) 
ORDER BY (location <-> '0020000001000010e64029d460d2a8aee0404bc8bb0955ea17'::geometry) LIMIT 10;
```

Where as the same query without the `IN` ***does*** use the index?

```
SELECT * FROM shops 
WHERE ("version" = (SELECT "version" FROM "version" LIMIT 1)) 
ORDER BY (location <-> '0020000001000010e64029d460d2a8aee0404bc8bb0955ea17'::geometry) LIMIT 10;
```

This is affecting us since we updated from postgres 9 to 11. I was able to trace back the issue to the above selection.

**EDIT: Add qry analyze**

First query (without index application):

```
"Limit  (cost=25260.30..25260.32 rows=10 width=1275) (actual time=254.809..254.814 rows=10 loops=1)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=25260.30..25260.39 rows=36 width=1275) (actual time=254.807..254.809 rows=10 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: ((shops.location <-> '0101000020E6100000E0AEA8D260D4294017EA5509BBC84B40'::geometry))"
"        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 54kB"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=41.88..25259.52 rows=36 width=1275) (actual time=0.099..215.201 rows=58179 loops=1)"
"              Join Filter: (shops.version = version.version)"
"              ->  HashAggregate  (cost=41.88..43.88 rows=200 width=4) (actual time=0.014..0.016 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                    Group Key: version.version"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on version  (cost=0.00..35.50 rows=2550 width=4) (actual time=0.009..0.010 rows=1 loops=1)"
```

Second query:

```
"Limit  (cost=0.28..440.04 rows=10 width=1275) (actual time=0.194..0.233 rows=10 loops=1)"
"  ->  Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=0.28..1574995.44 rows=35815 width=1275) (actual time=0.193..0.230 rows=10 loops=1)"
"        Join Filter: (shop.version = version.version)"
"        ->  Index Scan using shop_location_idx on shops  (cost=0.28..101549.81 rows=71630 width=1267) (actual time=0.182..0.213 rows=10 loops=1)"
"              Order By: (location <-> '0101000020E6100000E0AEA8D260D4294017EA5509BBC84B40'::geometry)"
"        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..48.25 rows=2550 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=10)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on version  (cost=0.00..35.50 rows=2550 width=4) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=1 loops=1)"
```

**Solved**

See the answer below, with thanks to @JimJones and @JimMacaulay

Comment: Hi, could you `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` both queries and add it to your question? It might give us a clue ;-)

Comment: other thoughts (probably unrelated): are the columns `version` in both tables also indexed? have you tried a join? how do you know the the gist index isn't being used?

Comment: You are using LIMIT 1 in your second query, which gives you only one record. For this one record, there will be no impact even there is Index/ No index

Comment: @JimJones looking at the explain, it doesnt do an index scan; I tried adding an index to the version table, but that didnt help.

Comment: @RoyB is `version` in the table `shop` also indexed? As I see both queries are doing a `Seq Scan`. The cost of the LIMIT 1 query will be always lower.. see Jim's comment above.

Comment: @JimJones it is indexed with a BTREE, but indeed it somehow doesnt seem to pick that up. However, that doesnt explain to me why the geometry ordering isnt using an index.. That is the thing that is really slowing it all down so much.

Comment: I found it, thanks to you guys... I might have mixed up some scenarios, but placing an index on the `version` table fixes the first query to use the index on both columns.

Comment: @RoyB awesome! wanna answer the question and marking it as solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an index on the version table somehow helps postgres towards using the index on the `location` column as well.

So adding this index is the fix for the 1st query:

```
CREATE INDEX version_idx
    ON public.version USING btree
    (version)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Correctly applying indexes on all columns inside the lookup, helps postgres to make a performant query plan.